# Entity Framework Core: how to combine selects and retain order?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

What I currently want to achieve is this, but as `IQueryable` without the need of allocating the result to memory, as the request itself already contains pagination information. I am really not getting my head around it how to solve it, I already tried `Union`, but that does not retain any order at all.

Basically I want to order the items based on the `State` and the `Updated` properties. That's all one table and `base.OnQuery` returns the `DbSet<HKTDownload>`. Is it somehow possible to solve that only by `OrderBy`? If so, how?

```
    var list = new List<HKTDownload>();
    list.AddRange(
        base.OnQuery(context, request)
            .Where(x => 
                x.State == HKTDownloadState.DownloadContent
             || x.State == HKTDownloadState.Unpack
             || x.State == HKTDownloadState.Repair
             || x.State == HKTDownloadState.MoveFiles)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
            .Include(x => x.DownloadConfig)
    );
    list.AddRange(
        base.OnQuery(context, request)
            .Where(x => x.State == HKTDownloadState.DownloadNZBFile)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
            .Include(x => x.DownloadConfig)
    );
    list.AddRange(
        base.OnQuery(context, request)
            .Where(x => x.State == HKTDownloadState.QueuedForDownloadContent)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
            .Include(x => x.DownloadConfig)
    );
    list.AddRange(
        base.OnQuery(context, request)
            .Where(x => x.State == HKTDownloadState.Queued)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
            .Include(x => x.DownloadConfig)
    );
    list.AddRange(
        base.OnQuery(context, request)
            .Where(x => 
                x.State == HKTDownloadState.Completed 
                || x.State == HKTDownloadState.Error)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
            .Take(200)
            .Include(x => x.DownloadConfig)
    );
    
    return list.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Sorry, that looks like you could do it with CONCAPT, returning an IQueryable that is composed of multiple parts that are CONCAT. WIll be a monster SQL statement , though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional `OrderBy` to get everything in the right order.

```cs
return base.OnQuery(context, request)
    .OrderBy(x => (
                x.State == HKTDownloadState.DownloadContent
             || x.State == HKTDownloadState.Unpack
             || x.State == HKTDownloadState.Repair
             || x.State == HKTDownloadState.MoveFiles
         ) ? 1 :
            x.State == HKTDownloadState.DownloadNZBFile
           ? 2 :
            x.State == HKTDownloadState.QueuedForDownloadContent
           ? 3 :
            x.State == HKTDownloadState.Queued
           ? 4 : (
               x.State == HKTDownloadState.Completed 
            || x.State == HKTDownloadState.Error
         ) ? 5 : 6
    )
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Updated)
    .Include(x => x.DownloadConfig);
```

Comment: Looks promising, but would ThenByDescending not destroy the order by? because there are asychron state changes, Queued can also happen by user interaction but i want the output to be orderd by progress, that's the most important thing. as you dont want to see newly queued downloads rather then the ones progressing.

Comment: No `OrderByDescending` would overwrite the previous ordering, but `ThenByDescending` does not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.thenbydescending?view=net-7.0

Comment: Ah, it just leaves the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 as order key, ThenByDescending retains the previous order only sorting where the keys are the same, i see. It really is doing exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You could also potentially order by whatever these enum values are, if they happen to be in the correct order.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is extremely bad even from a non-ORM statepoint.

Let's get going with that:

- This looks like you load various queries into one list - maintaining order. There is nothing making a query that uses CONCAT to combine multiple subqueries. How bad the SQL side performance is - try it out. Because this will be a monster and you may run into problems maintaining the locks too long, reducing db side throughput. I have similar queries, where every sub-element has 100k+ rows and you have a dozen of them - and I have to issue them with specific configurations to make sure I am not blocking a db table too long.

Why is that query really bad, though?

Because even without that you could use an IEnumerable and return that. Loading them into a List is totally unnecessary to start with - you could always just have an IEnumerable and return yield them, running one by one. NOT offloading to SQL, but - not materializing them in a list and returning a result much faster ;)